# display html content without using webviw in android

Tags: android, html, show

I wan to display html contents without using webview in android.

Contents are result of html parser.

But by now, I don't know how to do it. Is there any clue or example?

I think I need some example code to study it.

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Html.fromHtml()`

**Example :**

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));
```

Best Example [here](http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-display-html-in-android-view/).